Showing a particular $k$ satisfies the inequality $\frac{\delta}{2}\ge\frac{16}{2^k\varepsilon^2\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^2}$ and constraint $k\ge 8$
While working on a problem, I hit the following subproblem.

Given any $\varepsilon,\delta\in (0,1)$, find a $k\ge 8$ such that the following inequality is satisfied $$\frac{\delta}{2}\ge\frac{16}{2^k\varepsilon^2\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^2}$$

The way I went about solving this is to note that $\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^2\le 1$ and then doing as follows:
$$2^k\ge \frac{32}{\varepsilon^2\delta\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^2}\ge \frac{32}{\varepsilon^2\delta}\Rightarrow k\ge \log_2\left(\frac{32}{\varepsilon^2\delta}\right)$$
Hence I claim that $$k=\max\left\{8,\left\lceil\log_2\left(\frac{32}{\epsilon^2\delta}\right)\right\rceil+1\right\}$$
But I am getting stuck when showing that this $k$ actually works by plugging it in.
If $k=8$, then we know that $$\left\lceil\log_2\left(\frac{32}{\epsilon^2\delta}\right)\right\rceil+1\le 8\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2\delta}\le 4$$ and plugging this in, we see that $$\frac{32}{2^8\varepsilon^2\delta\left(1-\frac1{2^8}\right)^2}\le \frac{(256)^2}{2(255)^2}<1$$ which confirms this.
But I am not sure how to go about for the other value of $k$, namely when $k>8$.

Am I wrong in choosing my $k$ which is the source of the issues? Or can this be proven to work? If the former, please help me choose a better $k$. If the latter, a proof will suffice.

Any help is appreciated!

By a quick search, I got $(\varepsilon,\delta)=(\frac 12,\frac{12549}{50000})$ for which both yours and pushinproto's give $10$, while the smallest integer satisfying the inequality is $9$. So, it seems that there is a better $k$.

I think your general approach is fine. The original inequality is equivalent to the following:
$$\delta\epsilon^2 \geq \frac{32}{2^k - 2 + \frac{1}{2^k}}$$
Note that the RHS goes to 0 in the limit, so in general any $k$ large enough should suffice. Since $\frac{1}{2^k} \geq 0$, it suffices to find a $k$ satisfying
$$\delta\epsilon^2 \geq \frac{32}{2^k - 2}$$
Some algebra yields that $k = \log\left(\frac{32}{\delta\epsilon^2} + 2\right)$.
As far as plugging things back in, we can see that:
$$\frac{32}{2^k - 2 + \frac{1}{2^k}} \leq \frac{32}{2^k - 2} = \frac{32}{\frac{32}{\delta\epsilon^2} + 2 - 2} = \delta\epsilon^2$$
as desired.
